# Get Mouse-Position on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, position, mouse

i´d like to get the mouse-position relative to my canvas.
I know this is normally done by:
Mouse.GetPosition(my_canvas);
I heard of problems doing this on transparent canvases. My canvas isnt transparent, but it looks as follows...

```
<s:Editor x:Name="canvas_editor"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" >


                    <!-- Background Grid -->
                    <s:Editor.Background>
                        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,10,10" 
                                     ViewportUnits="Absolute" >
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25,25"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        <Pen Brush="LightGray" Thickness="0.5"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </s:Editor.Background>


                    <Button Content="Add" s:Editor.Left="10" s:Editor.Top="10" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="IO" s:Editor.Left="10" s:Editor.Top="30" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_IO"/>

                </s:Editor>
```

This Editor is a custom-control derived from a canvas. 
My canvas sits on the right bottom corner of the screen.
Now when i try to get the position as mentioned above, i get the following position: -300 -140...
which corresponds to 0,0 on the main window.
Why is this happening ? can anyone help me or has already dealt with a similar issue ?

all the best
mq

Comment: You should add a complete example to get more help. Where is the code to get the position? Hard to help you without all information ;)

Comment: I don't know where is your problem? What is you question?